# Data preparation for NER in CONLL 2003 BIO format

Tags: python, nlp, lstm, named-entity-recognition

To train my own NER over custom entities, I need my dataset preapared with CONLL-2003 format as specified in - https://github.com/yongyuwen/sequence-tagging-ner.

How would I convert my text documents (.txt) files to specified CONLL-U format - like [Word POS CHUNK NER].

Note: For the given text documents, I am already having custom NER tags.

Sample data (training_data.txt):

```
(Sample 1)
This Agreement of Work is made pursuant to the Global Developer Master Services Agreement effective as  of May 24, 2018, as amended on March 28, 2016, between MA[CUSTOM_ENTITY], lnc.[CUSTOM_ENTITY] whose registered office or principal place of  business is at 520 Madison Avenue, Ahmedabad, India, whose registered  office or principal place of business is at Building A, Atlantis de la,  Switzerland, collectively and ABC[CUSTOM_ENTITY] LLC[CUSTOM_ENTITY] a wholly owned subsidiary of  Amazon Services Ltd and having its registered office at 113 Red Avenue, 10th Floor, New York, NY 13027.

(Sample 2)
This Agreement of Work is subject to the terms and conditions of the Master Agreement for Technology  Consulting Services between Vignesh[CUSTOM_ENTITY] Services[CUSTOM_ENTITY] Limited[CUSTOM_ENTITY] and ABD[CUSTOM_ENTITY] LLC[CUSTOM_ENTITY], an  entity wholly owned by ABC[CUSTOM_ENTITY] Holdings[CUSTOM_ENTITY] LLC[CUSTOM_ENTITY].

(Sample 3)
This Agreement of Work dated October 22, 2013 between Google[CUSTOM_ENTITY] Services[CUSTOM_ENTITY] Limited[CUSTOM_ENTITY]  and Avaya[CUSTOM_ENTITY] Communications[CUSTOM_ENTITY] Management[CUSTOM_ENTITY], LLC[CUSTOM_ENTITY] and any of its operating subsidiaries and  affiliates which receive Services from Vendor incorporates and is governed by the terms and  conditions contained in the Master Services Agreement Services, by and between Avaya and Vendor.
```

Where [CUSTOM_ENTITY] is the tag for new entity to be trained with NER.

Comment: how do your .txt documents look like? can you post a simple example?

Comment: @DavidBatista I have added sample data of .txt file as you have requested. Thanks.